# Increment Date by 1 set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hopefully someone can help me here. I have set up a React component. All I want is to increment the date on click, it does seem to store the date correctly in nextDate variable but the state of selectedDate is not changing. I have tried many things but cant figure it out.

````
export default class ScheduleV2 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { selectedDate: Date() };
 this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(selectedDate) {
 var nextDay = new Date(this.state.selectedDate);
 nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
 console.log("the next day is", nextDay);
 this.setState = {
   selectedDate: nextDay,
 };
 console.log(selectedDate);
}

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <h2>Next Day</h2>
     <h3>{this.state.selectedDate}</h3>
     <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.state.selectedDate)}>
       Next Day
     </button>
   </div>
 );
}
}```
````

Comment: `setState` is a function, not a property. So `this.setState({selectedDate: nextDay})`...

Comment: hi @HereticMonkey tried that too, and treid it again just now in case, unfortunately that also doesnt seem to change the date :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because `date.setDate()` mutates the original date and React doesn't handle mutatable state (so it doesn't update/rerender the DOM). Instead, a workaround is to update a number in days which then updates the date...

```js
function App() {
  const [date, updateDate] = React.useState(new Date());
  const [days, setDays] = React.useState(0);

  const incrementDate = React.useCallback(() => {
    setDays(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }, []);
  
  const decrementDate = React.useCallback(() => {
   setDays(prevState => prevState - 1);
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    updateDate(prevState => new Date(Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  }, [days, updateDate])
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Selected Date:</h1>
      <p>{date.toString()}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementDate}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrementDate}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Or.. make your life easier and use a *better* date system like [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) or [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)

```js
const format = "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a";

function App() {
  const [date, updateDate] = React.useState(moment(new Date(), format));

  const incrementDate = React.useCallback(() => {
    updateDate(prevState => moment(prevState, format).add(1, "day"));
  }, []);
  
  const decrementDate = React.useCallback(() => {
    updateDate(prevState => moment(prevState, format).subtract(1, "day"));
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Selected Date:</h1>
      <p>{date.format(format)}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementDate}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrementDate}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I mean, `moment` is huge and is usually regarded as a viable option mostly for running on the server. There are plenty of lightweight alternatives such as `date-fns` or `fecha`.

Comment: Thank you Matt your answer works perfectly. No wonder state wouldnt update with such similar code I use for updating a counter etc. "not able to update mutatable state" ill need to look more into that.... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting next day then change your `handleClick()` method like this..

```
handleClick(selectedDate) { 
 
 this.setState ((prevState) => {
  const nextDay = new Date(prevState.selectedDate + 1);
  nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
   return {
     selectedDate: Date(nextDay)
   };
 });
 
}
```